Selecting a single item from SwiftData
I’m trying to learn more about using SwiftData. One thing I can’t work out involves reading from the data store.
I’ve learned that you can read the entire store using @Query, but that you can also filter it using @Query(filter: …). I gather that the filter is the only way you can fetch a single item from the store.
I can make it work with a statement like:
@Query(filter: #Predicate<TestData> { xb in xb.id == "…" })
var testhing: [TestData]

But I can’t use a variable in the xb.id == … expression.
How can I select one item from the SwiftData store at run time?
I have a working sample to illustrate what I’ve tried and what I want to achieve.
//  Sample Model
    @Model
    class TestData {
        @Attribute(.unique) var id: String
        var value: String
        init(id: String, value: String) {
            self.id = id
            self.value = value
        }
    }

//  Sample View
    struct Test: View {
        @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext

        @State var id: String = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication!.bundleIdentifier!
        @State var data = "Hello"

        //    Would like to use id above
        @Query(filter: #Predicate<TestData> { xb in xb.id == "com.apple.Notes" })
        //  @Query
        var testhing: [TestData]

        var body: some View {

            VStack {
                Text(testhing.count>0 ? "\(testhing[0].id): \(testhing[0].value)" : "Empty")
                //    Add Dummy Data
                Button("Add Sample", action: {
                    for i in ["org.mozilla.firefox", "com.apple.dt.Xcode", "com.apple.news", "com.apple.Notes", "com.apple.AppStore"] {
                        let test = TestData(id: i, value: i.uppercased())
                        modelContext.insert(test)
                    }
                })
            }
            .onAppear {
                id = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication!.bundleIdentifier!
            }
        }
    }

//  Menu Bat App
    @main
    struct XBarApp: App {
        var body: some Scene {
            MenuBarExtra("Hello", systemImage: "questionmark.bubble") {
                Test()
                .modelContainer(for: TestData.self)
            }
            .modelContainer(for: XBarData.self)
            .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
        }
    }


Also note that @Query is not the only way to fetch data, if you are outside a view or only need to fetch data once you can use one of the fetch functions in ModelContext together with a FetchDescriptor
